# What is purpose of e and item in event handler of CollectionViewSource.Filter event?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Below is a filtering logic for 
    CollectionViewSource.filter event . i have following doubts

1.What is e and item , we haven't declared them still are able to use them .How?

2.What does `AuctionItem product = e.Item as AuctionItem` do ? What type casting does as keyword do here ?

```
private void ShowOnlyBargainsFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
AuctionItem product = e.Item as AuctionItem;
if (product != null)
{
    // Filter out products with price 25 or above 
    if (product.CurrentPrice < 25)
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

}

Here is the MSDN link for complete code : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Variable `e` is instantiated by the Framework not by you. Thats why you don't have to create it. You are called back for each item that is to be filtered. `Item` is the object to test the filter against (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.filtereventargs.item(v=vs.90).aspx). It's your data - in your case an AuctionItem.
2. `as` is a cast operator which evaluates to `null` if a cast is not possible instead of throwing an exception (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx).
   In your case it casts `e.Item` to `AuctionItem`. If `e.Item` is not an `AuctionItem`, your product variable will be `null`.

Comment: Can u plz explain :  You are called back for each item that is to be filtered . statement

Comment: That is how the filter works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx You are called back to determine for each item if it is to be included in the collection or not. YOU provide the code to decide if an item will be included or not, for example for viewing. The CollectionViewSource can't know how you want to filter so it asks you.